# postgresql Jsonb ? is not working

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am using postgres 9.4 and i have a table test_table where the definition is:

```
id (primary key) integer, meta_data json, version integer
```

The Table data is as follows:

```
1;"{"id":99,"file_name":"test.pdf"}";0
2;"{"id":101,"nest1":{"nest_name_1":"oxford"},"file_name":"test2.pdf"}";0
```

I want to find all the primary keys that contain the keyword oxford. so the expected result is 2.

I am still trying to find a solution and i was trying something like:

```
select * from test_table where meta_data ? 'oxford'
```

gives me:

> Error: operator does not exist: json ? unknown

thats making me confused. surely postgresql 9.4 has ? operator right? what is going on?

can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `?` applies to [`jsonb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), so your query should be:

```
select * from test_table where meta_data::jsonb ? 'oxford';
```

Note that the query wont find any row because value `'oxford'` is in nested object.

Comment: you are right, i just noticed it and i was gonna delete the question. but since you answered it already, i will accept the answer when i am allowed (in about three minutes.)